# Qt: How to find the nearest existing ancestor of a path, which itself may or may not exist

Tags: qt, path, qfiledialog, qdir

Motivating example:

> In a previous session, the application has stored some path selected
>   by the user. In the meantime that path may have been deleted, moved,
>   renamed or the drive unmounted. The application would now like to let
>   the user browse for a path via a `QFileDialog` and for the user's convenience, the previous path is passed as the
>   starting directory of the file dialog, as presumably the new
>   path is likely to be near the old path. Unfortunately, if
>   `QFileDialog` is given a starting path that does not exist, it
>   defaults to the current working directory, which is very unlikely to
>   be helpful to the user as it is typically the installation directory
>   of the application.
>
> So we would like to preprocess the old path to point to a directory
>   that actually exists before passing it to `QFileDialog`. If the old
>   path doesn't exist, we'd like to replace it with the nearest directory
>   that does.

So how does one take a file path (which may or may not exist) and search "up" that path until one finds something that actually exists in the filesystem?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, at least for me. The title says "file path that actually exists" but the body says "file path which may or may not exist". However, if I understand correctly, the goal is to **get the (absolute path to the) parent directory of the specified file path**, am I right?

Comment: @kefir500, I agree that the question is confusingly worded, but no, your understanding is not correct. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the two approaches I've come up with so far, but suggestions for improvement would be very much appreciated.

## Searching upward until a path exists:

```
QString GetNearestExistingAncestorOfPath(const QString & path)
{
    if(QFileInfo::exists(path)) return path;

    QDir dir(path);
    if(!dir.makeAbsolute()) return {};
    do
    {
        dir.setPath(QDir::cleanPath(dir.filePath(QStringLiteral(".."))));
    }
    while(!dir.exists() && !dir.isRoot());

    return dir.exists() ? dir.path() : QString{};
}
```

## Searching downward until a path doesn't exist:

```
QString GetNearestExistingAncestorOfPath(const QString & path)
{
    if(QFileInfo::exists(path)) return path;

    auto segments = QDir::cleanPath(path).split('/');
    QDir dir(segments.takeFirst() + '/');
    if(!dir.exists()) return {};
    for(const auto & segment : qAsConst(segments))
    {
        if(!dir.cd(segment)) break;
    }
    return dir.path();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
QString getNearestExistingPath(const QString &path)
{
    QString existingPath(path);
    while (!QFileInfo::exists(existingPath)) {
        const QString previousPath(existingPath);
        existingPath = QFileInfo(existingPath).dir().absolutePath();
        if (existingPath == previousPath) {
            return QString();
        }
    }
    return existingPath;
}
```

This function utilizes the [`QFileInfo::dir()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#dir) method which returns the parent directory for a specified path. The code is looped until the existing path is met *or* the paths in the two latest iterations are identical (this helps us to avoid the infinite loop).

From the [`QFileInfo::dir()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#dir) docs:

> Returns the path of the object's parent directory as a `QDir` object.
>   **Note:** The `QDir` returned always corresponds to the object's parent directory, even if the QFileInfo represents a directory.

**I still recommend you to run some tests because I may be missing something.**